# Is a contractive algebraic homomorphism between unital $ C^{*} $-algebras a unital $ C^{*} $-algebraic homomorphism?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

We know that a $ C^{*} $-algebraic homomorphism from a unital $ C^{*} $-algebra $ A $ to a unital $ C^{*} $-algebra $ B $ is a linear multiplicative mapping that preserves units and respects the $ * $-operations.

There is an exercise that states:

> If a mapping $ \Phi: A \to B $ between unital $ C^{*} $-algebras is linear, multiplicative and
>   $$
> \forall x \in A: \quad \| \Phi(x) \|_{B} \leq \| x \|_{A},
> $$
>   then $ \Phi $ is a $ C^{*} $-algebraic homomorphism.

I know that as $ \Phi $ is linear, it respects the $ * $-operations. But how can I prove that $ \Phi $ preserves units? Does the proof require the condition that $ \| \Phi(x) \|_{B} \leq \| x \|_{A} $ for all $ x \in A $?

Comment: "I know that as $\Phi$ is linear, it respects the $*$-operations." What is the logic here?  You need to use the contractive hypothesis to show it respects the $*$-operations; that is the whole point of the exercise, and it is not implied by linearity alone.

Answer (score 3):

With your definition of C$^*$-homomorphism as unit preserving, the assertion is not true.

Consider $A=M_2(\mathbb C)$, $B=M_3(\mathbb C)$, and 
$$
\phi:x\longmapsto\begin{bmatrix}x&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\phi$ is a contractive $*$-homomorphism that is not unital.

If you require $\phi$ to be surjective, then it is unital by a basic algebraic fact: for any $y\in B$,
$$
\phi(I)y=\phi(I)\phi(\phi^{-1}(y))=\phi(I\phi^{-1}(y))=\phi(\phi^{-1}(y))=y,
$$
so $\phi(I)=I$ by uniqueness of the identity.

Comment: True, but I think the main point that joker is overlooking is that it must be proved that the map is in fact a $*$-homomorphism.